# Confusion on Data Transport Commands in Github

Tags: github

I looked all over for this. I cannot find any answers anywhere, nor is this in the Github official or unofficial glossaries.

[image]

What is a/an...

"Workspace"

"Index"

"Local Repository"

"Remote Repository"

...in relation to my computer and the GitHub Servers? Is the workspace my computer? Is the Local Repository my computer? Do I setup the Remote Repository on my personal server somewhere? I can memorize these words and the commands that move data from one to the other, but they mean nothing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Workspace: your project directory; aka Working Directory

Index: Git's record of items you've `add`ed from your workspace; aka Staging Area

Local repository: the collection of commits and branches stored in your project's `.git` directory

Remote repository: another repository for the same project which is outwith your project directory. (Not necessarily on a different computer but nearly always is.)

To demonstrate:

```
$ cd my-dev-work
$ mkdir fooproject
$ cd fooproject                   // your workspace

$ git init                        // creates local repo and index, with default branch 'master'
$ echo "hello world!" >> foo.txt
$ git add foo.txt                 // foo.txt added to the index

$ git commit -m "Created foo.txt" // foo.txt added to local repo in a new commit

$ git remote add origin https://github.com/joebloggs/foo.git
// adds a link to a remote repository, in this case on Github, named 'origin'

$ git push origin master          
// push your local'master' branch to the 'origin' remote repo,
// including the new commit containing 'foo.txt'
```

Comment: Semi-topically - this is one of my favourite Git talks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duqBHik7nRo